# How to Read a Line from File in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml, readfile

I am in trouble with `OCaml`, because I want to read the lines from a text file, and I'm using this code to do the job:

```
    let parse3ac() = 
    let lines = ref "" in
    let chan = open_in "3ac" in
    try
      while true do
        lines := input_line chan;
    print_string(!lines);
      done;
     with End_of_file -> close_in chan;print_string("End Of File");;
```

But it only prints in the console "End Of File", but the lines from the file, doesn't appears.

What is wrong with this code guys?

Thks 4 all!!!

Edited:

Actually I have discovered the reason it isn't working.
It is very simple, the code above works very well, but the file "3ac" that I had created previously using `OCaml`, wasn't properly closed, and then it would be impossible to read the file.
Thanks everybody, and like I said before the code works so everyone can use that.

Thanks .

Comment: This code is about as imperative (non-functional) as it could be.  If it matters to you, you might move a little toward a more functional style once you get it working.

Answer (score 1):

This code works, I tested it and it writes the lines of the file 3ac (without newlines as you don't print them) and then "End Of File". Are you sure the file 3ac is not empty ?

Comment: Actually I have discovered the reason it isnt working.
It is very simple, the code above works very well, but the file "3ac" that I had created previously using OCaml, wasnt properly closed, and then it would be impossible to read the file.
THks everybody, and like I said before the code works so everyone can use that.

THks.